# Header files in other folders not being found C++

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Hi I am trying to compile my own C++ file that works in tangent with an existing large codebase. I have my header file linking my file to the codebase. My problem arises when CMake compiles, it finds all the header files in the folder of the file I initially linked, but does not find any files outside of that scope. How do I tell CMake where to look?

For example
My file -> hello_world.cpp
Top of hello_world.cpp #include "config/codebase/otherFile.cpp"
CMake manages to find all the files in the "codebase" folder but no files in the parallel folders inside config.

Comment: Each include must be exactly stated. it should be exact relative/absolute path, or it should in include_directories list.

Comment: Have you told the compiler about all the locations to find headers (the `-I` option for g++)?

Comment: Add the additional folders in `include_directories()`